# Parse a sample of an XML in a VBA array

Tags: xml, vba, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML with VBA. The XML have the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <T>
   <P>
      <D> 
         <A> something 1<A> 
         <A> something 2<A>
      <D>
   <P>
   <P>
      <E>                     
         <B> something 3<B> 
         <B> something 4<B>
      <E>
   <P>
<T>
`
```

I'm trying to write a piece of code which loop in the second node of P to get the value of B in an array [something 3, something 4]. If you have some bit of code which "flatten" an XML in array it is also interesting.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, you can use the `Microsoft XML library`. Here's a `Sub` that do what you need:

```
Sub getNodesValues()
    Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument30 'Need Reference "Microsoft Xml, 3.0"
    xmlDoc.Load ("C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\test.xml") 'Set your file name
    xmlDoc.async = False

    Dim nodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim mainNode As IXMLDOMNode

    Dim arr() As String 'Array that will store results
    Dim index As Long: index = 1

    'This uses xPath to access an element
    Set nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//P/E/B") 
    ReDim arr(1 To nodeList.Length)

    'For each node in List
    For Each mainNode In nodeList
        arr(index) = mainNode.Text 'Store value in array

        'Show node name and value in immediate console
        Debug.Print mainNode.nodeName & ":" & mainNode.Text

        index = index + 1
    Next mainNode

    'Do what you have to do with your array
    '[..]
End Sub
```

#### Important things to notice

You load your file through this line:

```
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\test.xml") 'Set your file name
```

And with this line you tell the library what to search in your `.xml` file:

```
Set nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//P/E/B")
```

In this example, we're searching a tag `P` in any position, which contains the tag `E`, which contains the tag `B`. You can change this with anything you need.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Usse xml linq :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim xP As List(Of XElement) = doc.Descendants("P").ToList()

        Dim results = xP.Elements().SelectMany(Function(x) x.Elements().Select(Function(y) New With {
                                                                                   .parent = x.Name.LocalName, _
                                                                                   .child = y.Name.LocalName, _
                                                                                   .text = CType(y, String)
                                                                               })).ToList()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Sorry!!  Was using VB.Net

Comment: No problem, just to advise people who don't know.